# Module's function auto running?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I can't figure out why the function that I've called auto runs when I run the script, without pressing the button.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog


root = tkinter.Tk ()
root.title("fool")
root.geometry("300x300")
br = tkinter.Button(root, text ="Carica File", command = filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r"))
br.pack()
```

Comment: What is your question?  It is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're passing the result of the call

```
filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r")
```

to the `command` parameter. To be able to get this result, the function is executed and you're seeing the dialog right away. What you probably want to do is just provide the name of a function to call when the button is pressed, so you could define one as

```
def foo():
    filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r")
```

and use

```
command = foo
```

In the `Button` call. What you're doing in your code above corresponds to `command = foo()` instead (which executes the function), and not `command = foo`.

If you want to do everything in the same line, and not define an extra function, you could also use a lambda and write:

```
command = lambda: filedialog.askopenfile(mode="r")
```